# Minecraft Bedrock - dying whilst falling down a 1x1 shaft

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm running Minecraft Bedrock (v1.16.201) and for a long time I've had a 1x1 shaft (~60 blocks deep) with a pool at the bottom which I use as a quick drop to a diamond-level mine.

I've recently added a beacon which gives me Speed II enchantment and now, when I enter the drop shaft I often take damage about 3-4 times during the drop resulting in death about two thirds of the way down.  Sometimes the drop works - and sometimes I die.

Any idea what's causing this? There's no gaps in the shaft and the walls primarily comprise of Glass Block and Stone.  Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure so I'm not gonna leave a answer but mabey it has to do with your extra speed enchantment.

Answer (score 1):

I originally guessed that the Speed was causing you to hit an edge block during the fall or at the bottom of it, but this was cleared up by you stating that there were no gaps and that you were taking damage *while* falling. I honestly can't be too sure, my guess is that it has to do with the Speed II. There is a possibility that you may be glitching into the glass with your speed, which causes the drops that kill you, as I have accidentally done that before, but that's usually when I am using an Elytra and going at high speeds. I wouldn't cross it out however, since Speed II combined with speed from falling could probably achieve a similar thing.

Try basic troubleshooting such as exiting and rejoining the world if you haven't already, and if it still persists, lower the beacon to Speed I. If it still persists, then remove Speed entirely, my assumption is that is the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and suggestions.  A reboot/relaunch of MC doesn't resolve the issue.  It definitely only occurs when Speed II is applied (drop shaft is just outside beacon range so I can test with or without Speed II applied).  Glitch sounds likely - maybe I should report it as a bug but I wasn't sure if this was by design or not. Thanks.

Comment: @ChrisWalsh Reporting it as a bug would likely be the best possible route. Glad I could help, even if just a little bit!